# Session Replication in Tomcat

Tags: java, session, tomcat, tomcat7, session-cookies

We have two separated servers and configured with Delta session manager to replicate session between two servers. The replication between them was successful and if I down any one of the server it works fine, but it always shows an error at catalina.out that

> object are not serialized

Comment: Not serialized or not serializable? Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: Feb 25, 2019 4:57:33 AM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager requestCompleted **SEVERE: Unable to serialize delta request for sessionid [ADBAD379AB211182AC6A8724BF200345]
** This the error log on catalina.out at the session replication, but session replication was successful. Is that create any problem when we move this server to live?

Comment: The rest of the stacktrace should indicate which object is not `Serializable`.

Comment: yes, in trace we can see the object. But the problem is we are unable to serialize the object it will take time to change code, So without serialize can we make this session replication in to live?

Comment: Just adding `implements Serializable` fixes it in most cases.

Comment: If tomcat stopped itself due to this error, after we went live means it will be critical to handle, So kindly provide a detail about that tomcat will not get sop due to this error.

Comment: Ok I will add implements Serializable, and get back to you soon

Comment: It works thanks @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Apache Tomcat 7 we can uncomment `<Cluster  className=”org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster”/>`  tag and update cluster detail something liek below.

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
        expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"        
        notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
    
    <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
    
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
        address="228.0.0.4"
        port="45564" frequency="500"
        dropTime="3000"/>           

        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">                
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>              
        </Sender>           
        
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" 
        address="auto" port="4000" autoBind="100"
        selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"/>                     
        
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>         
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>   
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>                      
    
    </Channel>
    
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" />       
    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener" />       
    
</Cluster>
```

Also, we need to add `workers.properties` at `apache/conf/` path.

**Please note** this file has to be placed in all the Tomcat servers which will run in a cluster.

You can read more in detail [here](https://ashishontech.xyz/session-replication-in-tomcat/).